# Where is ViewState stored?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Where is a ViewState Stored? Is it stored in Server or Client Side?

I have a huge data which should be stored for some process. I was using Session. But when moved from one page to another im not able to clear the session. So I thought of implementing ViewState. But when running with huge amount of data ViewState is throwing error?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You better look into the ASP.NET Cache, you might find it suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 11):

Viewstate is stored on page it self in encoded form. You can't access the viewstate in client side in a direct manner. You need to know the encoding/decoding algorithms to fetch the valuable data from this viewstate in clientside code.

You can use hidden variable to store data that will be used only on that page. Hidden variables are accessible from client side and server side code.

You can use Cache or session to store datatable (large data). They will have good performance as compare to ViewState.

The Cache is always using the machine's memory, the Session uses what has been configured:

In a web farm the Session can be local (which works only if affinity is set), or remote (state server or database, or custom), but the cache is always local.

So, storing a DataTable in the cache will consume memory, but it will not use serialization.

PS: storing a DataSet instead of a DataTable will change almost nothing.

[Refer Cache Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14017/using-cache-to-store-Data-in-datatable-for-custom)

Comment: read more about viewstate from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/04/06/viewstatemode-in-asp-net-4-0.aspx

Comment: "You can't access the viewstate in client side.". As a matter of fact, you can access it, since it is not encrypted (by default). However, it can't be changed, since it contains a hash that will be verified by ASP.NET.

Comment: @Steven, I am agree with you that we can access the viewstate but it will be not usefull to access them because how we will get the actual/decoded value from the viewstate variable.

Comment: When hacking web sites, I find it very useful to be able to access the viewstate, so you can't say it isn't useful ;-) As a developer however, there is not really any need to access the view state of your own pages client side. That's probably what you mean :-).

Comment: Is there any suitable way to store it other than ViewState?? i will be having a big DataTable itself which contains around 100 thousand records at a time.

Comment: @smilu Please see the 3rd para in Answer "You can use Cache or session......."

Answer (score 8):

The ViewState is not stored on either side, it's send back and forth between the server and the browser on every request and response, so it's not a good idea to put a huge amount of data in ViewState.

Answer (score 4):

ViewState is stored where you tell it. By default, this is in a hidden field on the page sent to the client.

[ASP.NET can also store ViewState inside the Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.sessionpagestatepersister%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e. on the server, if you tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

Save large amount of data in view-state slowdown your site.
Use query string to fetch fresh copy from database on each page rather than save whole information from previous page.

Answer (score 0):

View State Information stores in hidden fields.
Information travels between server and client in this hidden fields.

For asp.net control,.. by default .net implements view state for all its control, thats why a textbox value does not lost when we click on a button of that page.