# Crafting a direct URL to some data built on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http-headers

Is it possible to craft a URL to some data for a site that uses asp.net? Below are some (altered) headers for the page. It is a page I use at work and loads very slowly. I would like to be able to craft a url for each person I need to look up, so that I can quickly and conveniently access the necessary data without having to navigate manually (and batch download the data, say every morning, so that I don't have to keep opening to the terribly slow webpage). Is this even possible without knowing __EVENTVALIDATION and __VIEWSTATE ? Or is there some way to determine these and craft them with the URL? Current searches have yielded nothing useful.
I want to end up with a list of urls like:
http://www.website.com/dir/DesktopDefault.aspx?...stuff...&name=burgundy,%20ron
http://www.website.com/dir/DesktopDefault.aspx?...stuff...&name=smith,%20jon
...

```
Request URL:http://www.website.com/dir/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=1&tabid=19
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1985
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Cookie:.ASPXAUTH=49F8DEC657CDB04FAFF7690E70144ED3077; ASP.NET_SessionId=vlmpmcmjlj2fbve1jyhuo355; portalroles=29A1B587C6A40A6A25A8A3C74A69E1FEFA3FC95C5AB2F9D06EEA84B1D8C08775E5FC9ED0825A1F33C86E055E8D460AB8D8BE1039DD6C207B62D5EA2EE7B66363391B3CDE3FAB501BB47DD7496D5920AF9357756D0C2BBC57F560F40699CC90B633BCAE87161ACCC53F4AEEBD9655238115607D65
Host:www.website.com
Origin:http://www.website.com
Referer:http://www.website.com/dir/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=1&tabid=19
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.149 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
tabindex:1
tabid:19
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__LASTFOCUS:
__VIEWSTATE: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
__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEWCgKKq4KCgL/65CcAwLygnLDQKyuOmWAwLF8uftCncQUIaUADBuq/xP51x49c427hZP
_ctl0:BaseContent:_ctl0:_ctl0:Persons:txtFindText:lastname, firstname
_ctl0:BaseContent:_ctl0:_ctl0:Persons:btnfind:Find
_ctl0:BaseContent:_ctl0:_ctl0:Persons:txtSelected_Person:FAKE, NAME
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:189
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 12 Mar 2014 20:04:26 GMT
Location:/dir/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=1&tabid=19&CMD=1
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: Do you need to craft a URL? Or an HTTP Request?

Comment: A URL. Is this even possible? I don't have permission to run code on these computers.

Comment: I don't even know what you're asking. You want to create some URL's? A URL is just a string that you type. You want to download data from a server? Figure out what URL, then use a program like [WGET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) to download the file. That the server runs ASP.NET or not is irrelevant. From the client side, all you get is the resulting HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: This is new territory for me, so sorry if I am not being clear.

When the sites form is submitted, the form contains the asp.net hidden values __EVENTVALIDATION, __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTARGUMENT, __EVENTTARGET

To craft a URL that will properly retrieve the desired record, I need to pass these values. Unfortunately, __EVENTVALIDATION and __VIEWSTATE are long encoded strings. I need to craft a specific string to be able to submit the url.

if http://www.a.com/page?name=jon&__VIEWSTATE=1234 then [...]?name=jon&__VIEWSTATE=abcd then will not work. I need help understanding how to craft that url.

Comment: ViewState isn't stored in the QueryString. You can't pass it to the server that way. It's stored in HiddenFields. See [Where is ViewState stored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976852/where-is-viewstate-stored)?

Comment: So, is VIEWSTATE not even important to this problem then?

If I recraft the URL using  the form variables in the query string, I just get a refresh of the current page. I'm still messing something up.
http://www.website.com/DIR/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=1&tabid=19&CMD=1&&_ctl0:BaseContent:_ctl0:_ctl0:Persons:txtFindText=LASTNAME,%20FIRSTNAME&_ctl0:BaseContent:_ctl0:_ctl0:Persons:btnfind=Find